# I can't put a table inside a tcolorbox

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I'm writing a book and I cannot put a table inside a tcolorbox I previously defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\ejemplo}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=turquesaclar2, colframe=turquesaclar, title=EJEMPLO, lefttitle=4cm, breakable, enhanced]
    #1
\end{tcolorbox}}
```

This is what I wrote inside the tcolorbox after

```
\ejemplo{Se tiene el trinomio $x^2-3x-10$.

Sabemos que tanto p como m son negativos, por lo que uno de los números a y b debe ser negativo, y que el negativo debe tener un valor absoluto mayor que el del positivo, pues la suma de a y b es negativa.

Para encontrar todas las posibles soluciones descomponemos -10 y sumamos ambos factores hasta encontrar aquellos factores cuyos resultados coincidan con lo que buscamos (que su suma sea -3 y su producto sea -10):

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$a\cdot b$           & $a+b$        \\ \hline
$(-1)\cdot 10 = -10$ & $-1+10=9$    \\ \hline
$1\cdot (-10) = -10$ & $1+(-10)=-9$ \\ \hline
$(-2)\cdot 5 = -10$  & $-2+5=3$     \\ \hline
$2\cdot (-5)=-10$    & $2+(-5)=3$   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
```

Then it appears like this:

[image: How it appears]

As you can see the table is not there, what can I do? I don't know what to try. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Please add a complete minimal working example.

Comment: You cannot insert a float in the box. Delete `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`.

Comment: You can put the `tcolorbox` inside the `table`.

Comment: Welcome! Remember, `\begin{table}` really means `\begin{material that can float around and that will be numbered and captioned as a table}`: it has no sense to put it into a thing where it can't float around. If you still need the caption, you can use  `\captionof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `float.sty` and the option `H`, will helps you, as you are not providing proper `MWE`, I assumed that you are using standard class file, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ejemplo}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cyan!10, colframe=cyan!20, title=EJEMPLO, lefttitle=4cm, breakable, enhanced]
    #1
\end{tcolorbox}}

\ejemplo{Se tiene el trinomio $x^2-3x-10$.

Sabemos que tanto p como m son negativos, por lo que uno de los números a y b debe ser negativo, y que el negativo debe tener un valor absoluto mayor que el del positivo, pues la suma de a y b es negativa.

Para encontrar todas las posibles soluciones descomponemos -10 y sumamos ambos factores hasta encontrar aquellos factores cuyos resultados coincidan con lo que buscamos (que su suma sea -3 y su producto sea -10):

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$a\cdot b$           & $a+b$        \\ \hline
$(-1)\cdot 10 = -10$ & $-1+10=9$    \\ \hline
$1\cdot (-10) = -10$ & $1+(-10)=-9$ \\ \hline
$(-2)\cdot 5 = -10$  & $-2+5=3$     \\ \hline
$2\cdot (-5)=-10$    & $2+(-5)=3$   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tcolorbox` already loads `xcolor` package and option `many` already loads `skins` and `breakable` libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put a caption, you don't need a `table` environment and `float`, a `tabular` (which is not a floating environment) is enough.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[skins,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ejemplo}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cyan!10, colframe=cyan!20, title=EJEMPLO, lefttitle=4cm, breakable, enhanced]
    #1
\end{tcolorbox}}

\ejemplo{Se tiene el trinomio $x^2-3x-10$.

Sabemos que tanto p como m son negativos, por lo que uno de los números a y b debe ser negativo, y que el negativo debe tener un valor absoluto mayor que el del positivo, pues la suma de a y b es negativa.

Para encontrar todas las posibles soluciones descomponemos -10 y sumamos ambos factores hasta encontrar aquellos factores cuyos resultados coincidan con lo que buscamos (que su suma sea -3 y su producto sea -10):

{\par\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$a\cdot b$           & $a+b$        \\ \hline
$(-1)\cdot 10 = -10$ & $-1+10=9$    \\ \hline
$1\cdot (-10) = -10$ & $1+(-10)=-9$ \\ \hline
$(-2)\cdot 5 = -10$  & $-2+5=3$     \\ \hline
$2\cdot (-5)=-10$    & $2+(-5)=3$   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\par}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]